# How to check if function is equal to a particular value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For example, I have a function below.

```
function :: x -> y -> z -> v -> Bool
```

I want to do something if function is equal to True in guards like:

```
| something = do something
| function == True = do something
| something = something do something
```

How can I implement it using a correct syntax?

Comment: I might be missing something, but how would a function be equal to a value? Do you mean the return of a function?

Comment: Please add the full use case; this is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It never makes sense to compare whether “a function is equal to `True`” (except in a theoretical discussion with booleans in [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)).

Comment: Oh yeah. I mean a return value of function. @Carcigenicate

Comment: @JamesRaquel Your function takes 3 arguments, yet in your example, you don't supply any. What data needs to be given to the function? You can't get a value return without applying the function to something first.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply call the function in your guard.
Example:

```
bar :: Int -> Int
bar x = x*x

baz :: Int -> Int
baz x = x+2

baw :: Int -> Bool  -- note: this returns a Bool instead
baw x = x < 12

foo :: Int -> Int -> String
foo x y
  | x > 2               = "a"
  | bar x + baz y < 100 = "b"
  | baw x               = "c"
  | otherwise           = "d"
```